# Как правильно решить пример?

Tags: c#

помогите пожалуйста правильно решить пример. а лучше объяснить как.

1. Создайте массив из 5 чисел типа float.
2. Используя цикл while, вычислите сумму всех чисел массива.
3. Используя цикл for, вычислите произведение всех чисел массива.
4. Выведите оба результата в консоль.

   ```
   float[] a = new float[5] {2f, 5f, 5f, 6f, 4f };//я так понял нужно сразу проинициализировать массив

   float sum = 0f; // это как я понял нужна дополнительная переменная которая будет выводить сумму чисел массива


        while (sum <= 5)// условие я так понял должно выполняться таким образом так как чисел 5 в массиве
        {
           sum = a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]+a[4];// данный способ знаю не верный, но как записать правильно не могу понять.

           Console.WriteLine("Сумма элементов массива равна " + sum);

        }
        for(float p = 0; p < a.Length; p++)
        {
            p = a[0] * a[1] * a[2] * a[3] * a[4];// аналогично с умножением, понимаю что не верно так писать код.
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
   ```

В комментариях написал что попытался сделать и вот не знаю правильно ли это. поэтому прошу совета как правильно сделать и если можно с пояснением на простом языке для новичка. спасибо.

Comment: В циклах надо пробежаться по элементам массива и просуммировать(умножить) их и вывести результат. т.е. записи вида a[0] * a[1] * a[2] * a[3] * a[4] неверные. 
у while условие выполнения неверное (нужна переменная счетчик для того чтобы пробежать по элементам массива и смотреть на размер массива)

Answer (score 2):

Оригинально конечно

```
while (sum <= 5)// условие я так понял должно выполняться таким образом так как чисел 5 в массиве
 {
    sum = a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]+a[4];// данный способ знаю не верный, но как записать правильно не могу понять.

    Console.WriteLine("Сумма элементов массива равна " + sum);

 }
```

Если сумма окажется меньше пяти, то будем продолжать суммировать и выводить. А так как элементы не меняются, то оно будет долго-долго.

Наверно хотят где то так

```
int i = 0;
float sum = 0;
while (i<a.Length) {
  sum = sum+a[i];
  i++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Сумма элементов массива равна " + sum);
```

В втором случае почти та же проблема. А если размер массива изменится?

```
float p = 1; // тут нужно строго 1, потому что иначе будет неверно считаться произведение
for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
  p = p * a[i];
}


Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Comment: По-моему `float` в c# не может выступать в качестве индекса массива. Нужно исправить в цикле for тип переменной `i`

Comment: да, конечно. я на шарпе последний раз писал где то в 2001-2002, когда в одном с компьютерных журналов появилась заметка о нем

Comment: @KoVadim я попробовал как вы написали выше, но вот что выходит. при сумме элементов выдается сумма сразу не всех элементов, а сначала 0+2=2, 2+ 5=7, 2+5+5 = 12, 2+5+5+6 = 18, 2+5+5+6+4 = 22. а из условия задачи я так понял нужно сразу вывести 22.        По умножению я не совсем понял почему Console.WriteLine(p) за циклом? в таком случае выводится 1. а если в теле цикла то вообще ничего не выводится.

Comment: Если Console.WriteLine(p)  написать внутри цикла, то оно будет отрабатывать каждую итерацию цикла. Видимо в случае суммы Вы это и сделали ( в моем варианте как раз этого и нет).

Comment: @KoVadim, да точно. спасибо. а вот по поводу умножения, не подскажите, переменная int i = 0; объявлена еще в самом начале. в цикле for я не могу ее уже объявлять, а если напишу for( ; i < a.Length; i++), то в итоге получаю 1. или заменить просто другой переменной вместо i ?

Comment: если Вы напишите  `for( ; i < a.Length; i++)`, то начальное значение i будет равно 6 и цикл не будет выполнятся ни разу. напишите так  `for( i=0; i < a.Length; i++)` или используйте другую переменную вместо `i`

Comment: @KoVadim  понял. спасибо большое.